# Displaying data with query component on Pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I want to display a data (in my case, a String) by using `Query component` on Pentaho CDE. However, nothing is displayed.

Here is what I did:

On DataSource Panel:

[image]

The query is

> select city_name from tb_city where city_id='1';

and it gives '`NYC`' as result.

Then On `Component Panel - Query Component`:

[image]

With a JS function on Post Execution:

> function f() {
>   document.getElementById('header_c').innerHTML =myresult; 
>    }

where `header_c` is the name of the column where I want to display the query result.

I think there's no prob with this function and other stuffs because when I change `myresult` to any string like 'HELLO' in the function, it's displayed.

Does anyone have an idea where's wrong? I verified and the query has no prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this code in your post fetch. where **abc** is **Result Var**

```
function fun(abc) { 
document.getElementById('qq1').innerHTML =abc.resultset;
}
```

Comment: Oh perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: By the way, I want to use this variable in my query in Datasources, like "select * from table where city_m=${myresult}", however it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: if the you want to pass parameter in datasource of other component then you can manually set it like  write this line dashboad.setParam('paramName',abc.resultset)  in above function.

Comment: Alright, here is what I did :
function fun(abc) { 
document.getElementById('qq1').innerHTML =abc.resultset;
Dashboard.setParameter('city_m_param',abc.resultset);
}
and in my query "select * from table where city_m=${city_m_param}. This query is used to display a barchart but since I've changed to it, it's not beeing displayed. Do I have to do extra things?

Comment: I made an another post to explain this problem, it would be nice if you can have a look! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611878/how-to-pass-a-variable-obtained-from-query-component-into-a-query-on-pentaho-cde