# How to pass a variable obtained from query component into a query on Pentaho CDE?

Tags: pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I managed to get data as variable with `Query component`. 
Now I want to pass this variable into a query.
Here is what I did:

**On Query Component:** myresult='NYC' in my example.

[image]

**The query on Datasources:** I use this one to display a chart, when I change ${myresult} to 'NYC', it works fine. But with ${myresult}, the chart is not displayed.

[image]

I also tried with

```
> Dashboard.setParameter()
```

On post fetch of Query Component, but still the same...

[image]

I also created simple param and select param (which is not displayed on dashboard) but it doesn't solve the problem.

It's been hours I'm stuck , would love to get some help!

**///////////////////////////////EDITED/////////////////////////////**

**On Component Panel - simple parameter :**

[image]

**On Component Panel - Pie chart - Parameters :**

[image]

**On Component Panel - Pie chart - listeners :**  I selected param_city

**On Datasource - parameters of piechart query:**

[image]

Comment: Did you pass parameter myresult in your chart as listeners and parameters.please share snap of your chart component also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass parameter **myresult**  and **listner** in **Parameters** field of both chart  and datasource used for chart. 
[image: like this]

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots on the post!

Comment: I actually didn't put anything on Parameters - Value, so I did as you said, and it works perfectly.Thanks a lot, you saved my day again !! Thanks a lot!!