# How to show a report with dynamic parameters from a chart on Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a pie chart on my dashboard, using `click action`, I menaged to show a report that has one fixed parameter. Here is my JS function on click action:

```
 function showreport(scene) {
        var newWindow;
        if(scene.getCategory()=='POS'){
            newWindow=window.open("url_report?type_lm=POS", 'REPORT');
        }else{
            newWindow=window.open("url_report?type_lm=NEG", 'REPORT');
        }
    }
```

This one works fine.
But now I want to pass a dynamic parameter too ( the variable obtained with `query component`, it is stocked in `result var` (code_lm):
Here is what I did:

```
function showreport(scene) {
    var newWindow;
    var code_lm=this.dashboard.getParameterValue('code_lm');
    if(scene.getCategory()=='POS'){
        newWindow=window.open("url_report?type_lm=POS&code="+code_lm, 'REPORT');
    }else{
        newWindow=window.open("url_report?type_lm=NEG&code="+code_lm, 'REPORT');
    }
}
```

This one doesn't work, nothing is displayed by clicking the chart. I found this line  `var code_lm=this.dashboard.getParameterValue('code_lm');` causes the prob.

However, I do the same thing with `button component` :

```
function showreport() {
    var code_lm=this.dashboard.getParameterValue('code_lm');
    var newWindow =  window.open("url_report?code=" + code_lm,'REPORT');
}
```

and it works perfectly so I wonder why `this.dashboard.getParameterValue()` is not working in some cases.

Can anyone tell me where comes from the problem ?

Comment: replace your syntax with **dashboard.getParam('code_lm')**. it always works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if you want to pass value of parameter from query component then you need set parameter value by writing bellow code in **post fetch** of **query component**.

```
 function fun(code_lm) { 
dashboard.setParam('yourParamName',code_lm.resultset);
}
```

check out this may help you. [How to pass a variable obtained from query component into a query on Pentaho CDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611878/how-to-pass-a-variable-obtained-from-query-component-into-a-query-on-pentaho-cde) may help you.

Comment: I just changed it to dashboard.getParam() and works perfectly. Thanks so so much !!