# How to use result var obtained by query component in a datasource - query on Pentaho cde?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a variable obtained by query component, I want to pass it to a query on Data sources that will be used by another query component, here is what I did:

**1) DataSources - sql_company_id :**

[image]

**2) first Query Component :**

[image]

With a JS function on Post Fetch:

```
function f(company_id) { 
    dashboard.setParam('company_id', company_id.resultset); 
}
```

So company_id=1 in my example.

**3) DataSources - sql_company_name**

[image]

with parameter defined like below:

[image]

**4) second Query Component :**

[image]

with Post Fetch like this:

[image]

It is supposed to display the company name having company_id='1' but nothing appears.

When I change the second query to:

```
select company_name
from company
where company_id=1;
```

Then it works.

I'm not using correctly the variable {company_id} I suppose.
I had a very similar prob and got the solution so I did in the same way this time. Where I got wrong?

Comment: add **company_id** in second query component's listener field. also set execution at start to **False** . did you define your  parameter in **sql_company_name** datasource? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611878/how-to-pass-a-variable-obtained-from-query-component-into-a-query-on-pentaho-cde

Comment: yes, I defined the parameter company_id in sql_company_name datasource (screenshot under the query screenshot). How to add company_id to listener ? Because here, it's more selection of existing parameters. Should I make param_company_id (simple parameter) ?

Comment: you have to create simple parameter **company_id** if you haven't created yet.

Comment: okay, I created the simple parameter, set execution at start to false ( of the query component of company_name) but still not working. I must be missing out something important :(